# Running Scrapy in a For Loop hangs after first run

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, twisted

I want to run Scrapy in a for loop, one loop for each URL in a list. (NB: I don't want all these URLs as `start_urls`, I need them to run one at a time).

My first try gave me `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable` errors after the first iteration of the loop.

A search on SO gave a previous answers that says `process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)` should solve this problem. This got rid of the Twisted error, but now just hangs after the first iteration of the loop. This is not a duplicate of that question.

My current code is:

```
for url in urls:
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 4
    })

    process.crawl(MySpider, url)
    process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
```

The first URL runs fine, then it just hangs:

```
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 12, 21, 12, 29, 963422)}
2018-08-12 22:12:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a few Twisted modules to do it. Here's a quick example:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import defer, tasks

@tasks.react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl_my_sites(reactor):
    runner = CrawlerRunner({})
    for url in urls:
        yield runner.crawl(MySpider, url)
```

Answer (score 1):

For looping through a list with scrapy I think using "start_requests" is a good idea:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open('./input/id_urls_10k.csv','r') as csvfile:
        urlreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
        for row in urlreader:
            if row[1]=="y":
                yield scrapy.Request(url=row[2],meta={'urlkey':row[0]})
```

Comment: The problem persists. The crawler disconnects after the first yield of request. Doesn't loop